# jQuery ajax post dynamic url insertion

Tags: php, jquery

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "OMFG.php", data: info, success: function(){ }});
```

is what I'm using atm as a test and it works fine.

I need to get the url from the link I'm clicking, so I do:

```
var url = $(this).attr("href");
```

which works fine if I alert it out(the link includes http://samedomain.com/etc.php), but the ajax function doesn't post if I insert it into the ajax code:

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", url: url, data: info, success: function(){ }});
```

Please help, as I'm screwed without this working.

Comment: Are you doing anything in that success?  There is a shorter [`$.post` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) if you're not doing more than the question.

Comment: I was going to throw a few functions, which needed the use of $(this), then remembered that it doesn't work and yes, I will be using $.post. However at the moment, I've got an alert in there (just a simple alert("success"); so I know it worked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the id attribute. For getting the link you need to fetch the href attribute:

```
var url = $(this).attr('href');
```

EDIT: See you just changed to href - if that still does not work try debugging by using

```
alert($(this).attr('href'));
```

and see if it alerts an url and if it is correct.

EDIT 2: Well, check in firebug in FF or Javascript Console in Chrome for errors or what url the script really is trying to post to. Depending on the rest of the code your url-variable might be out of scope if it is defined within some function or something.

Comment: sorry, I mistyped it when I was using doing the question, I am using href in my actual code. This is not the issue.

Comment: The paragraph under it (right under it) states that it does, I have tried it again, just to double check, does work.